# Compound adjectives verb+verb or verb+ and+verb

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

In an article published online I found recently 'smash and grab' as an adjective of raid (?not sure). In lists of compound adjectives this combination (verb+and+verb) rarely appears. I can also remember 'fly and drive and 'hit and run' which are quite frequent. I do remember seeing also verb+ verb as a possible compound, but at present cannot recall an example. Can you help me here with other examples and confirmation of relatively frequent use of such compounds in modern day English?

Comment: 'cash and carry' 'wash and go' 'pick and mix' 'kiss and tell'

Comment: Since you are happy with that, I shall post an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Can you confirm that all of them may also be used as adjectives? Is hyphenation possible for these compounds? And finally, can you recall verb+verb (no and) combinations ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for lists are rarely questions having more than interest value.

Comment: I am new to this community and didn't know that asking for a confirmation of the existence of a compound adj that is missing in some grammars ( and other references online would be off topic. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an English speaker in the UK, I have noticed a few verb+verb expressions.

'Cash and carry' is a warehouse, usually, where folk buy quantity not quality. We would say, 'I'm going to the cash and carry to buy fifty tins of beans for the camping holiday', so the compound becomes identified by 'the' as a location.

'Wash and go' is a ridiculous term for either a laundry or a carwash. Again, it becomes, 'the wash and go' as a business enterprise.

'Pick and mix' is where sweets, often little wrapped sweets and candy of various types, are displayed in tubs and one chooses from here and there and the mixture is weighed out. Again its an identifiable entity, 'the pick and mix in Woolworths is worth seeing'.

'Kiss and tell' describes newspaper stories where someone has had an affair then goes to the media and spills the details for financial gain, usually, or just notoriety, maybe. It is just an expression and is not identifiable; though one could speak of 'a kiss and tell' story.

All of these are in common use in the UK. None of these are adjectives.

Comment: But OP specifically asked for adjectives.